# "Презентую" - какое это время?

Tags: вид, будущее-время

Слово "презентую" это настоящее время несовершенного вида или будущее время совершенного?

Одновременно ведь быть не может?

Comment: Может-может. Полно таких, особенно на -овать: https://gramdict.ru/search/?symbol=св-нсв

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a biaspectual verb (*двувидовой глагол*): a verb whose perfective and imperfective forms are identical.

Other verbs like this are *жениться, креститься, казнить* and [many more](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Russian_biaspectual_verbs)

Most biaspectual verbs end in *-овать* and *-ировать*, but there are some ad-hoc ones as in the example above.

Note that they can be homonyms, like the aforementioned *креститься*, which means "to accept baptism" as a perfective verb and "to bless oneself, to make the sign of the cross" as an imperfective one.